# А что, "слышь ты" никогда не разделяются запятой?

Tags: вводные-слова, обращение

> Немедленно ему позвонила и ору: «Слышь ты!!! Ты ведь самый
>   настоящий!!! Ты - ДРУГ!!!»

А мне предлагают:

[**Слышь ты**, *вводн.* то же, что слышь, слышь-ка. *Он, слышь ты, правду говорит. Он, слышь ты, сам едет.*](https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/ogegova/223870)

[А, слышь ты, Василиса Егоровна правду говорит.](https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/ushakov/1030066)

А я слышу запятую, я её проговариваю.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Если слышите, то и ставьте, ведь есть "слышь ты", а есть отдельно "слышь" и отдельно обращение "ты". Вот Толковый словарь Ефремовой
https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/efremova/279588 утверждает:

> слышь - част. разг.-сниж.; = слы́шь-ка
>
> 1. Употребляется как вводное слово с целью привлечь внимание к чьим-либо словам, соответствуя по значению словам: имей в виду, послушай.
> 2. Употребляется как вводное слово с целью разъяснить что-либо, соответствуя по значению словам: видишь ли, знаешь ли, кажется, как
>    будто.

Если мы употребляем в первом значении, получается ***слышь, ты... = послушай, ты...***

Всё нормально, запятая оправдана самостоятельным употреблением **ТЫ** вне вводного слова с частицей.